# if else block still print out results even inputs are empty on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

I have an `if else` block that checks if input fields are empty before saving data. However, even if one of the inputs is empty, the controller text is still printed out. Can someone explain why?

```dart
void submitData() async {
  List<newIngredientList> _ingName = [];
  for (var textInputWidget in _textInputList) {
    if (textInputWidget.controller.text.isEmpty ||
        textInputWidget.quantityController.text.isEmpty) {
      showCupertinoDialog(
          //message empty field
      );
    } else {
      _ingName.add(newIngredientList(
        textInputWidget.controller.text,
        textInputWidget.quantityController.text,
      ));
      print(textInputWidget.controller.text);
      print(textInputWidget.quantityController.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i see only the input with text. empty inputs are not printed

Answer (score 0):

try printing the textfield text before checking the condition and see if it's truly empty, you can also provide additional code for further assistance.

```
 void submitData() async {
  List<newIngredientList> _ingName = [];
  for (var textInputWidget in _textInputList) {
       print(textInputWidget.controller.text);    //add this
       print( textInputWidget.quantityController.text);   //add this
    if (textInputWidget.controller.text.isEmpty ||
        textInputWidget.quantityController.text.isEmpty) {
      showCupertinoDialog(
          //message empty field
      );
    } else {
      _ingName.add(newIngredientList(
        textInputWidget.controller.text,
        textInputWidget.quantityController.text,
      ));
      print(textInputWidget.controller.text);
      print(textInputWidget.quantityController.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as suggested, I added the print, and it gives empty string:
I/flutter (15435): 
I/flutter (15435): 
kind of like controllers are initialised as empty string I guess...